# custom module not defined in nodejs express app

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, node-modules

we made a custom module for express app but getting this error  `somename is not defined`

here is our code

`app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var somename = require('./somename/common');
// console.log(wahapar.ucfirst("d"));
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

`common.js`

```
module.exports = {
    ucfirst: function(str){
        //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ucfirst/
        // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
        // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
        // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        //   example 1: ucfirst('kevin van zonneveld');
        //   returns 1: 'Kevin van zonneveld'
        str += '';
        var f = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        return f + str.substr(1);
    },
};
```

`ejs view`

```
<%= somename.ucfirst("this is a string") %>
```

while `console.log(somename.ucfirst("d"));` is showing output in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your module as a local variable into express app.

```
app.locals.somename = require('./somename/common');
```

Then you will be able to use inside ejs templates.

From the express docs [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals)

> The app.locals object is a JavaScript object, and its properties are
> local variables within the application.
>
> Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the
> life of the application, in contrast with res.locals properties that
> are valid only for the lifetime of the request.
>
> You can access local variables in templates rendered within the
> application. This is useful for providing helper functions to
> templates, as well as app-level data. Locals are available in
> middleware via req.app.locals

Comment: app.local.somename means -> `express().locals.somename` , You should pass that variable after your required express module.

Comment: @runningmark have you ever tried solution , may you give any feedback?